# Random numbers to a sum of constant value in excel

Tags: excel, random, sum

I would like to generate 14 random numbers in excel between a certain range (3 to 5) that adds up to a certain value lets say 48. The numbers generated between 3 to 5 can be repeated.

I used the `=RANDBETWEEN(3,5)` from columns D5:Q5. And then in another sheet where I want the result to be displayed I wrote `=ROUND(Sheet5!B2/SUM(Sheet5!$B$2:$O$2)*48,0)`

Everytime I press F9 it generates random numbers that is fine. But not everytime the total adds up to 48. Sometimes the sum is higher and sometimes the total is lower than 48. How can I make it to a total of 48 instead of random sum.

Comment: numbers generated shall not be in decimals.

Comment: So set it up using the solver, you can add an integer constraint as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So set it up - I laid it out like this but you can change that:

[image]

You can add flexibility by bringing the constraints for the 3 and 5 onto the sheet - which keeps them visible when you keep trying different scenarios. Like this:

[image]

So, based on the comment:

[image]

Went back to the other method to state the constraints.

Comment: Is it also possible to run the solver for multiple outputs at once?
I have a total of 5 entries for different items. Each entry has a different sum of random numbers like in previous case was 48 for the first entry. If I may process for all entries (48, 52, 58, 50, 55) all at once while keeping the other parameters/constraints same as before without running the solver independently for each entry?

Comment: Yes, have the sum of the results as the objective and set it to a max or min. Then set constraints for each of the results to be 488, or 62 or 71 etc just add the constraints for each set.

Comment: @Jack check the edit, just expands the array really. Any further expansion you should be able to figure out.